# Connect To PC With Computer Name

Tags: android, android-networking

in my application there is a PC (win 7 As web Server ) and 1-n android devices(As Client).
 the networking is via modem/router.
the android devices should connect to PC and send/receive data.
the problem that i have is that the ip that modem/router assigns to PC is different each time network resets
 so i want to connect to PC with PC-Name like :

```
public static String ServerAddress = "Reza-PC";
```

or find a way to convert Computer-Name to Computer IP.
how can i do this ( if it is even possible )?

Answer (score 0):

Consider connecting your server pc from outside of your router with WAN ip. Also you need to perform [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Comment: thanks. but is should be local.i know what is port forwarding but how it can i use it to solve my problem ?

Comment: You can manually set an ip address to your computer (for preventing it to have random ip address) then try to connect.

Comment: Alternatively you can set a domain name to your local pc. I've found  [this](http://lifehacker.com/124804/geek-to-live--how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-your-home-web-server). Hope this helps.

Comment: Then check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/491295/how-to-publish-local-domain-names-on-my-local-network) out. It explains how to setup a DNS server on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JCIFS library to implement the CIFS/SMB Networking protocol… put simply, it allows you to send and receive files over a Network and/or a Windows PC with shared folders.

Example :

```
private boolean startSmbTransfer(String filename) {

    boolean IS_SUCCESS = true;
    File sourse = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/FolderName/" + filename);

    final String NETWORK_FOLDER = "smb://PC-NAME/FOLDER-NAEME/";

    SmbFileOutputStream sfos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                null);
        String path = NETWORK_FOLDER + sourse.getName();
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);

        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[512];
        is = new FileInputStream(sourse);
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
            sfos.write(buf, 0, c);
            sfos.flush();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        IS_SUCCESS = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            sfos.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            IS_SUCCESS = false;
        }
    }
    return IS_SUCCESS;
}
```

check the below link for detail information and example of using this library,
[using JCIFS library in android](https://durgemeister.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/mapping-a-network-with-jcifs-and-android/)

Comment: i don't need file sharing. i want to connect to web sever.